# HTML for listing the folder contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, shell, button

I have html file which do button operations on specific events.
When i tried to execute a shell script from html , I am not able to do the same.
Please help me to run shell script inside html.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using for the backend? .Net, php?

Comment: Please provide some code and structure. This is too broad an non-specific.

Comment: This is not a "give me code" website

Answer (score 2):

HTML does not have this capability.

(Nor, for that matter, does core JavaScript. Extensions from the host environment might provide that feature, but it would depend on the host environment. "A webpage with a `<script>` element" is a host environment that does *not* provide that functionality.)

You need to select a different technology. It could be one that outputs HTML though.

Answer (score -1):

At first, this is not a simple "I have a problem, solve it for me!" site. But since it's SO's goal to educate, it would be wrong to push you away.

### Let's start with your problem:

HTML can't do that, nor vanilla JavaScript. If the server with the files on it does support PHP and you have access to it in order to store a .php file on it, you can do it by using PHP:

```
$directory = "some/directory/you/want/to/display/";
$files = scandir($directory);

print_r($files);
```

Comment: "JavaScript are run on the client side" — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_server-side_JavaScript_implementations

Comment: "you can do that with PHP " — That assumes the particular server supports PHP.

Comment: "If you have access to the server (I think so, why would you ask then?)" — Questions where the OP wants to treat an HTML document as a deployable application and not something served over HTTP are not uncommon here.

Comment: I'll edit my answer. @Quentin

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply. Can u please help me with how to execute a shell script from html..

Comment: The issue got solved . My question was correct . I didnt ask for  code and all , I asked for the logic. Anyway am explaining the answer for someone who needs this : " I didi it with php" We can access our systems folder using php and run the scripts :                                              shell_exec('cd /path;./script.sh');